# Netty Server - how to invoke methods from the outside?

Tags: java, netty

I'm currently trying to build a tcp server with netty. The server should then be part of my main program.

My application needs to send messages to the connected clients. I know I can keep track of the channels using a concurrent hash map or a `ChannelGroup` inside a handler. To not block my application the server itself has to run in a seperate thread. From my pov the corresponding `run` method would look like this:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        EventLoopGroup bossEventGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerEventGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
            bootstrap
                .group(bossEventGroup, workerEventGroup)
                .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .childHandler(new MyServerInitializer());

            ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.bind(8080).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            workerEventGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            bossEventGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

But now I have no idea how to integerate e.g. a `sendMessage(Message message)` method which can be used by my main application. I believe the function itself has to be defined in the handler to have access to the stored connected channels. But can someone give me an idea how to make such a function usable from the outside? Do I have to implement some sort of message queue which is checked in a loop after the `bind`? I could imagine that then the method invocation looks like this:

```
ServerHandlerTest t = (ServerHandlerTest) future.channel().pipeline().last();
(if newMessageInQueue) {
    t.sendMessage(...);
}
```

Maybe someone is able to explain me what is the preferred implementation method for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would go to create your own application handler to manage the business behavior within your own Netty handler, because that is the main logic (event based).

1. Your own (last) handler take care of all your application behavior, such that each client is served correctly, directly within the handler, using the ContextCHannelHandler ctx

Of course, you can still think of a particular application handler that would do something as:

1. Creation of the handler (in the pipeline creation within MyServerInitializer) will initiate the handler to look for a messageQueue to send
2. Then polling on the messageQueue to send but to the right client using a hashMap

But I believe it is far more complicated (which queue for which client or a global queue, how to handle the queue without blocking the server thread - not to do -, ...).

Moreover, sendMessage method ? Do you want to talk about write (or writeAndFlush) method ?

Comment: yes, how can I call write or writeAndFlush from outside a netty class?